# Discord.js time out error for members.fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch a specific user in a server with 1000+ members that Is offline, but It doesnt get It. 
How i can fetch offline users in a server with 1000+ members? 
My current code:

```js
let user = client.guilds.cache.get('server id').members.cache.get('memember id') || client.guilds.cache.get('server id').members.fetch('member id')

if(user) {
   console.log('the user is in the server')
}
```

Thanks in advance and Sorry for bad english!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: Nope, I already have the members intent activated.

Comment: Both in your developer portal *and* listed in your client options?

Comment: Also, you don't need to check the cache first and then fetch, fetching first checks the cache anyway unless you pass `force: true` in its options parameter.

Comment: @Elitezen yes, all is enabled