# DiscordJS: guildMemberAdd console.log not returning anything

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Server member intents have been turned on in the discord developer portal for this application.

Here is my code:

```
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
client.commands = new Collection();

require('dotenv').config(); //initialize dotenv


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send(`Welcome, ${interaction.member.tag}`); 
    console.log(`test`);
});
  

//make sure this line is the last line
client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN); //login bot using token
```

Nothing is being logged to the console.

What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in your `<Client>` declaration.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
```