# Filter bots in counting server members using discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a variable that will store the user count of the message's guild id, but with no avail.

This is what I've got so far:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id)
var memberCount = guild.memberCount
```

It outputs the correct number of members but I'm not sure how to filter that amount so only bots will be excluded. I know this kind of question has been asked a many times on SO but the majority of the answers I've found would set the member count variable to 1, which I still don't understand why that happens.

Comment: make sure you have the right intents enabled and just do `client.guild.cache.get(message.guild.id).members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size`

Comment: @skara9 what would that intent be?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/

Answer (score 0):

Please note: You need the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent enabled for this to work

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(message.guild.id) // Fetch guild
guild.members.fetch().then(ms => { // Fetch members
  // Call reducer function, using ternary operator to count non-bots
  const nonBots = ms.reduce(acc, mem => member.user.bot ? acc : acc+1)
})
```