# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status') in discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to update my bot to Discord.js v14 but it gives an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
```

Here is the code where I am getting the error:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    let today = new Date();
    time = fancyTime(today);
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (!(list[i].presence.status == "offline")) {
            // If the person isn't online update array to a green circle and mark that they haven't gone offline
            if (list[i].presence.status == "idle") {
                timeList[i] = ":orange_circle:  " + time;
            } else if (list[i].presence.status == "dnd") {
                timeList[i] = ":red_circle:  " + time;
            } else {
                timeList[i] = ":green_circle:  " + time;
            }
            firstOffline[i] = 1;
        } else if ((list[i].presence.status == "offline") && (firstOffline[i] == 1)) {
            // If the person is offline and its the first time they're offline, 
            // Update array to the current time and mark that they've gone offline for the first time
            timeList[i] = ":white_circle:  " + time;
            firstOffline[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    // Backup the values to a text file
    fs.writeFile("timeListBackup.txt", timeList, (err) => {});
    fs.writeFile("firstOfflineBackup.txt", firstOffline, (err) => {});
}, 1000)
```

The full index file is [here](https://srcb.in/Kzlck3GSqB).

Comment: What intents do you want to enable with `intents: 3276799`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i was thinking at a time that my bot has maybe some missing intents that's why I gived all the intents to my bot using 3276799 but intents are not the cause of this problem

Comment: can you try to log the List data? Also, as far I know it is clientStatus instead of status. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @Lenzman i am not trying to get the bot status. i am trying to get the user status

Comment: at least one of the elements in `list` does not have a `presence` property

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you enabled the guild presences privileged intent? Not in the code — but in the Discord Developer Portal. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/8289918) for more information.

Comment: @cherryblossom Yes, I have turned on all three intents in the Discord Developer Portal.